# Serializing One to Many Relationship in django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two classes `person` and `test`, where one person can have several tests. I've tried serializing this but everytime I try to add an object using

```
person= Person.objects.create(title="mr",name="name",address="address",city="city")
```

it throws the error
`IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: appname_person.tests_id`

`models.py`

```
class Test(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    test_subject = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    test_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name

class Person(models.Model):
    tests = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`serializers.py`

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('test_name','test_subject','test_type')

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tests = TestSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'name', 'address', 'city')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the error in the serializer or in your data layer? From your code it looks like the object that you are creating is throwing an error, not the serialization.

Please try this

```
class Person(models.Model):
    tests = models.ForeignKey(Test, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also take a look at the difference and [use of null and blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/).

**EDIT**

I can also see another mistake. Your ForeignKey is a ManytoOne/OneToOne relationship that means that you one person is linked to a test. However in your serializer you are defining the field `test` with many=True. That serializer will expect a ManyToMany field. Please adjust your serializer or

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tests = TestSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'name', 'address', 'city')
```

or adjust your model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**EDIT 2:**

How to add tests to a person. I am not sure which documentation you are reading but this is how you should do it.

```
test1 = Test(...)
test1.save()
test2 = Test(...)
test2.save()
test3 = Test(...)
test3.save()

person = Person(....)
person.save()
person.tests.add(test1, test2)
person.tests.add(test3)
```

Remember to save the person before adding the tests because it will throw an exception otherwise. This must be done because the ManyToMany relation must know the id of the person object to which you are linking the tests.
Please refer to [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more documentation

Comment: but how do I add tests to the object person? the documentation suggests `Test.objects.create(person=person, test_name="test1", test_subject="Math" )`  but that throws the following error `TypeError: 'person' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
`

Answer (score 6):

Ok first of all, you got it the other way around, tests should have a foreign key pointing to the user model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="mr",blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Test(models.Model):
    tests = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=False)
    test_subject = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    test_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name
```

Comment: It seems to me that better replace `tests` with `person` as a more proper naming form.